# Map D3.js - ogr2ogr installation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to follow a map tutorial for d3.js. I tried following the other questions answered on stack overflow, but either there was no answer or not specific to my problem.

I've installed node.js, but when I try to install json and the other required libraries, it gives me the error of not a recognized command or an path does not exist.

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/

[image]

Comment: which is a linux command... you cant use that command on windows. just type ogr2ogr to see if it was correctly installed. Feel free to ask if you have problem installing does tools. It could be hard on windows

Comment: this library might interest you: https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps its a wrapper to create d3 maps easily through a javascript API

Comment: The best I managed to do was to download the libraries from the official website and run it from the install folder... Not extremely convenient, but I don't think you will convert files everyday

Comment: @BelowtheRadar I am still having difficulty. It says it is not recognizable. I also cannot download topojson

Comment: @Ashley do you mean to install it on your main user file? i normally install ogr2ogr to the global node-modules folder npm i -g ogr2ogr, but here is a link to a video of how to run it on windows: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnWw5AW63S0

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help for TopoJSON because I never tryed to install it myself, but you can install ogr2ogr (gdal) by downloading **GDAL 1.11 core** from http://www.gisinternals.com/stable.php (official source for windows binaries install)

- GDAL 1.11 32bit:
  http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1400-gdal-1-11-1-mapserver-6-4-1/gdal-111-1400-core.msi
- GDAL 1.11 64bit:
  http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1400-x64-gdal-1-11-1-mapserver-6-4-1/gdal-111-1400-x64-core.msi

Once its installed you may need to add the path of your GDAL directory into your windows **Path environement variable** to be able to use ogr2ogr command from the cmd shell